# Videos start but crash after a few seconds with MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

The method I use to play the video is:

```
-(void)playVideo:(NSString*)title {

NSLog(@"NAME: %@", title);
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *moviePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp4", title]];

MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath]];

mp.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];

[mp release];
}
```

After around 4 or 5 seconds the video stops, the previous screen is shown and I get the following error:

```
_itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTimeErrorKey = "Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 \"The operation could not be completed\" UserInfo=0xb19a220 {NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed, NSUnderlyingError=0xb17fac0 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (OSStatus error -12551.)\", NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12551)}";
```

Comment: Turns out the video I was trying to play was corrupted, I'll check this first next time.

Answer (score 0):

Try in Simple steps:

**Step 1:** Import MediaPlayer framework 
`#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>`

**Step 2:** Set delegate in .h file 
`UIViewController<MPMediaPlayback>`

**Step 3:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *fileLocation= [bundle pathForResource:@"file_video" ofType:@"m4v"];
    NSURL *vedioURL =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileLocation];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *videoPlayerView = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:vedioURL];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayerView];
    [videoPlayerView.moviePlayer play];
}

-(void)endSeeking
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}

-(void)stop
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code once:

```
-(void)playVideo
{
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:VideoURL]];
]
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];
[mp.moviePlayer play];
}
```

and make sure that

1. you have included MediaPlayer.framework
2. imported MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h file in your class